# TypeError: Cannot read property 'only' of undefined

Tags: casl

I am trying to use React Testing Library for my React project but it errors when trying to mount a component that imports CreatCanBountTo with the error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'only' of undefined`

`> 1 | const { createCanBoundTo } = require('@casl/react');`

I assume that it's due to casl not being initialised before the test runs.

Thank you in advanced for your help.

Comment: Casl internally uses `React.Children.only` Please provide a version of casl and react you use.

Comment: I was looking through github and saw that that was the case and so I assume it's calling this before React.Children has been set.

casl: 2.1.1
react: 16.13.1

Comment: How can this be possible? casl imports react, react define this function. So, the only possible way is if some library or jest do some magic with `require` calls

Comment: @SergiiStotskyi It is weird. I will keep digging and update this post if I find anything. Thank you for your help